# SSIS Creating Two Columns of Data in Flat File?

Tags: database, ssis

I'm having a strange problem with SSIS. I'm exporting some data from a database into a flat file. It comes out all fine - except that rather than displaying the data like this:

> ID  FirstName  LastName  Age

It comes out like this:

> ID  FirstName  LastName  Age  ID1  FirstName1  LastName1  Age1

Now, its not repeating the same data (ever), so the data might realistically look like this:

> 1  John  Doe  23  2  Jane  Doe  22

Why is it repeating like this?

Comment: Are you maybe not getting the line-breaks. It looks like it might be putting two rows (or more if it continues) on every line.

Comment: It is fixed width...I'm not seeing any way to put in line-breaks for fixed width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a fixed-width destination (even though it's "text") - it's **really** fixed width records (just in a text representation in the code page of your choice), one after another with nothing in between them.  So you need to add a record/row delimiter - in this case CRLF.

If you are in a Flat file destination component and click the new button to crete a destination data adapter right there - the "wizard" gives you four options.  The difference between fixed-width and fixed-width with row delimiters is that it just puts a little CRLF column on the end.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like the row delimiter from your file source is wrong. It's reading in two or more  rows as one row.

What are the output columns listed on the flat file source? If you see all of those you listed, I would almost guarantee this is the issue.

What is the actual layout of the source file? Is it delimited, fixed width columns, etc?

Comment: It is fixed width columns. Not sure how to see output columns?

Comment: Right click on the data flow path (green arrow) coming out of the flat file source. The Metadata tab will list your columns.

Comment: ID, LastName, FirstName, M_Initial, Sch_Date, AY_Token, Sch_Amount, POE_Token, Create_Dt, Status

Comment: Are those the actual columns you expect/defined? 10 columns in the source file? What happens after that? Are you applying any transformations?

Comment: I don't think there are any transformations. its just dropping them straight from the db into a flat text file. I recreated the project by dropping an ado net data source and a flat file destination.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I went into SMSS and did a straight export on the database table through the SMSS interface - and the same problem occurred!